# Encounter an issue while trying to remove unicode emojis from strings

Tags: python, regex

I am having a problem removing unicode emojis from my string. Here, I am providing some examples that I've seen in my data

```
['\\\\ud83d\\\\ude0e', '\\\\ud83e\\\\udd20', '\\\\ud83e\\\\udd23', '\\\\ud83d\\\\udc4d', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude43', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude31', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude14', '\\\\ud83d\\\\udcaa', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude0e', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude09', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude09', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude18','\\\\ud83d\\\\ude01' , '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude44', '\\\\ud83d\\\\ude17']
```

I would like to remind that these are just some examples, not all of them and they are actually inside some strings in my data.

Here is the function I tried to remove them

```
def remove_emojis(data):
    emoji_pattern = re.compile(
        u"(\\\\ud83d[\\\\ude00-\\\\ude4f])|"  # emoticons
        u"(\\\\ud83c[\\\\udf00-\\\\uffff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (1 of 2)
        u"(\\\\ud83d[\\\\u0000-\\\\uddff])|"  # symbols & pictographs (2 of 2)
        u"(\\\\ud83d[\\\\ude80-\\\\udeff])|"  # transport & map symbols
        u"(\\\\ud83c[\\\\udde0-\\\\uddff])"  # flags (iOS)
        "+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return re.sub(emoji_pattern, '', data)
```

If I use `"Naja, gegen dich ist sie ein Waisenknabe \\\\ud83d\\\\ude02\\\\ud83d\\\\ude02\\\\ud83d\\\\ude02"` as an input, my output is `"Naja, gegen dich ist sie ein Waisenknabe \\\\ude02\\\\ude02\\\\ude02"`. However my desired output should be `"Naja, gegen dich ist sie ein Waisenknabe "`.

What is the mistake that I am doing and how can I fix that to get my desired results.

Comment: Your text does not contain emojis chars themselves, just their hex representations with `\u` notation.Maybe all you need is `re.sub(r'\s*(?:\\+u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})+', '', data)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this should be the approach and I have been going for the wrong direction all along. Thanks for the great idea :) After I test this more I will update it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your text does not contain emoji chars themselves, but their representations in hexadecimal notation (*`\uXXXX`*), you can use

```py
data = re.sub(r'\s*(?:\\+u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})+', '', data)
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\\+u[a-fA-F0-9]{4})+` - one or more sequences of

  - `\\+` - one or more backslashes
  - `u` - a `u` char
  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{4}` - four hex chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YJdumw/1).